# Trouble with a for loop while rearranging a data.frame

Tags: r

I have a df :

```
Years Company ID    Name    Return
2003    23  622009  a       2323123
2008    14  622008  v       2312343
2009    43  622007  c       35345345
2006    32  622006  d       45656554
2005    67  622005  f       756756766
1999    60  622004  y       4564533
2001    63  622003  i       6756766
2002    66  622002  m       32423412
2008    68  622001  o       934833833
2004    48  622000  e       34132222
```

I am trying to rearrange the ordering of the `Years` column in ascending order (so the most recent year (2009) is on the top). In example :

```
Years Company ID    Name    Return
2009    62  622007  c       35345345
2008    62  622008  v       2312343 
2008    62  622001  o       934833833 
2006    62  622006  d       45656554
2005    62  622005  f       756756766
```

and so on...

I tried to do it with a for loop but it gives an incorrect answer. I get only the last row :

```
2005    62  622005  f       756756766

for (i in 1:length(unique(df$Year))){
  mm<-df[df$Year==unique(df$Year)[i],]
}
```

Could someone please guide me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `order` function for that:

```
df[order(df$Years,decreasing=TRUE), ]
```

Comment: I get an error while using your solution : Error in order(df$Years, decreasing = TRUE) : 
  argument 1 is not a vector

Comment: what kind? Please provide easily importable example in your question.

Comment: Error in order(df$Years, decreasing = TRUE) : 
  argument 1 is not a vector

Comment: But I do still wonder why the ´for´ loop only returns the last year data.frame...

Comment: Because in each iteration of the loop ``mm`` is overwritten.

Comment: Ok, but how should I then index it correctly to not be overwritten?:)

Comment: If you want to split your matrix do a ``lapply``: ``ldf<-lapply(unique(df$Year),function(x)df[df$Year==x,])``. You'll get a list of data.frames. You can rbind them using ``do.call("rbind",ldf)``.

Comment: Well at least the rewards are great. Remember, that if simple operation takes more than one line, there is probably a function to do that.